# Get the name of the state that is currently being transitioned to

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In some of my state resolves, I'm doing checks to make sure that the user is logged in, and if they aren't, I am redirecting them to the login state. After logging in, I'd like to redirect back to the original state they intended to visit.

My question is: how can I obtain the name of the state that is currently being transitioned to from within a resolve function (so that I can store it and transition to it after logging in)?

I've looked at the documentation for `$state`, and all I could find was `$state.transition` but this does not contain any helpful information.

Comment: `In some of my state resolves` - so you know exactly the state, and you can store it and then redirect to login, you can also check `$state.current` for informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to handle it from within the resolve function?

Typically this kind of activity would be handled from within the stateChangeStart event...

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with 
    // a 'transition prevented' error
})
```

(from the github wiki: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki and the API docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

You could store the toState in a Service till after successful login then change to requested state after.

Comment: Yes, I need to handle it in the resolve function because I need to delay the transition with a promise and the resolve function is the only way.

Comment: What I ended up doing was pretty much what you suggested. I just keep track of the last state was was being transitioned to from the $stateChangeStart event.